# Callback function to process output

Tags: python, subprocess, communication, temporary-files

Recently I've been messing around with `Popen`. I spawned a process in a background that writes the output to a `TemporaryFile`:

```
f = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
p = subprocess.Popen(["gatttool"], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = f)
```

Now it works in a way that I send a command to the process via `stdin` and read a bit later the temporary file. And it's non-blocking, so I can perform other tasks.

The problem is that `gatttool` sometimes generates some output byt itself (for example notifications). And I'm looking for a way to read this output without blocking the `TemporaryFile`.

My question:

1) Is it safe to read output from a `TemporaryFile` (50 lines) and hope that `subprocess` gracefully waits for me to read that data or will it terminate?

2) Is there an elegant way to create a callback function that will be called on every event on `TemporaryFile` (instead of having a thread that will run every one second and read the data)?

Comment: Looks like a good use case for a named pipe (instead of a plain file).

Comment: Perhaps: https://docs.python.org/2.2/lib/os-fd-ops.html and using simply pipe() ?

Comment: Personally, I like to use a higher level wrapper around subprocess like the `sh` module - that is why I'm posting comments instead of writing a proprer answer.

Comment: 1) what makes you think that reading from `f` file has any effect on the child process? Are you on Windows? 2) There are filesystem monitoring tools but it is [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096). Do you want to be notified (e.g., via callback) if `gatttool` produces a new line?

Comment: Actually I have found out solution where you create a pipe and gatttool pushes data on one end and on the second end you simply receive data. Seems to work for the moment

Answer (score 0):

To provide input/get output from a child process, you could use `subprocess.PIPE`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['gatttool', 'arg 1', 'arg 2'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
# provide input
p.stdin.write(b'input data')
p.stdin.close()
# read output incrementally (in "real-time")
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print line,
p.stdout.close()
p.wait()
```

Comment: Using ```PIPE``` as stdout will cause the application to hang. ```gatttool``` doesn't send EOF, it just sits there. Also, in your example you only provide single line of data, while in my application I provide some input and the output is gathered somewhere else

Comment: @Melon: obviously, you can write more than one line (call `p.stdin.write`) and you do not need to read in the same thread: you could put the reading loop into a daemon thread and invoke a callback for each line/byte/whatever you like. Internally, `subprocess` module may use `os.pipe()` so that you do not need to call it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Actually the resolution is very simple. Create a `pipe`, use the `gatttool` output as the input. The output of that pipe goes to a `thread`, that reads that output, line by line and each of that line is parsed. Checked it and it works. Please lock this question down.

```
# Create a pipe. "gatt_in" ins where the "gatttool" will be dumping it's output.
# We read that output from the other end of pipe, "gatt_out"
gatt_out, gatt_in = os.pipe()

gatt_process = subprocess.Popen(["gatttool", "your parametres"], stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                                stdout = gatt_in)
```

Now every time I want to send a command to `gatttool` I do this:

```
gatt_process.stdin.write("Some commands\n")
```

The result of this command will apear in `gatt_out`. In my case, this is handled in another thread.

Comment: do you mean `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`?

Comment: Could you post the code that you used to do this?  I am a Python N00b and I would really appreciate seeing this code.  I am running into the same problem.

Comment: downvote. Use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` instead of `os.pipe()`.

Comment: Using ```stdout=subprocess.PIPE``` blocks the application from execution and that's what I want to avoid

Comment: `PIPE` is implemented in terms of `os.pipe` on POSIX systems. If it blocks then your solution also blocks.

Comment: From what I see it doesn't. Maybe when I will have some more time I will post the code.